# Regarding error in controller when i pass array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails . Here is my problem:

```
@chapters = Chapter.all
@sections = Section.all
@selected_chapter = @chapter[0]
```

Right now this reads the first record but I want to pass a id so that @selected_chapter can read all the chapters that i have.

Here is my view/index code:

```
   <div id="container">
        <%=@selected_chapter.name%> <br/>
      <% @selected_chapter.sections.each{|section| %>
        <%=section.name%>  <br/>
        <% section.topics.each{|topic| %>
            <%=topic.name%><br/>
            <%=topic.description%><br/><br/>
         <% } %>
    <%} %>
   </div>
```

This code is working but only when i do @selected_chapters = @chapter[0].

Any help???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all chapters and all sections for all chapters, I think what you're looking for is this:

```
@chapters = Chapter.all
```

In your view you can then nest the loops further like this:

```
<% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
  <div id="container">
    <%= chapter.name %><br/>
    <% chapter.sections.each do |section| %>
      <%= section.name %><br/>
      <% section.topics.each do |topic| %>
        <%= topic.name %><br/>
        <%= topic.description %><br/>
        <br/>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you only want to read a specific chapter, you can do the following:

```
@selected_chapter = Chapter.find(id)
```

Where id is the id of the chapter you want to find. Keep in mind this won't necessarily mean that id = 10 will return the tenth chapter. If you want to return a specifically numbered chapter you can use limit and offset. For example, in Rails 3 you can get a single record starting at record 10 by doing the following:

```
Chapter.limit(1).offset(10)
```

Comment: thanks, but curiosity is there a way i can do something in this code @selected_chapters = @chapters[0], something like @selected_chapters = @chapters[id] or something so can read all chapter one by one...??

Comment: I tried to use @selected_chapter = Chapter.find(id) it give me error couldn't find chapter with id...??

Comment: That's probably because you don't have a Chapter in your database with the id that you passed. For example: Chapter.first will return the first chapter in the database. You can then do Chapter.first.id to see what the database generated as an id for that chapter.

Comment: Chapter.first gives me all the chapters that i have in database. I forgot to tell you that I am calling all this in diff controller not from chapter controller..so this could be the problem??

Comment: If you have a Chapter model and a chapters table in MySQL and you are using ActiveRecord, then Chapter.first (not Chapter.all) will give you a single Chapter record. Otherwise you have something that is not properly setup.

Comment: Yup I have a Chapter model and chapters table with has_many :sections. chapter.first gives me all chapters that I have in my database i dont no why??? I think there is some loop problem in view code...

Comment: The view code I posted is for a list of chapters, not a single chapter. I recommend opening your rails console (rails c) and trying theses commands to see how they work: Chapter.all, Chapter.first, Chapter.find(...)

Comment: Then you should be able to use your first view code with @selected_chapter = Chapter.first or my code example. It's up to you what you want to do.